# Change title of bookmark in Preview

Tags: macos, pdf, preview

In Preview.app (Mavericks version) bookmarks can be added (Cmd-D) to a PDF file and shown in the  sidebar.

The bookmarks all get the same title, which seems to be an excerpt from the first line(s) of the page.

So far, so good, except that in the document I am working on over the next many months, there is a page header on every page and it is the same for 300 pages or so.

The result is that the first text on each page is the same and all bookmarks look identical, except for the page number.

The problem is that I can't find a way to change the title of the bookmark once it has been created, so my side bar contains 20 indistinguishable bookmark titles, only differentiated by the page number.

If I knew the page numbers I wouldn't need the bookmarks, so I am very interested in a way to further differentiate the bookmarks, preferable by changing their title.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: There does not seem to be a way (at this moment). I have seen this question asked on various other forums as well. Unfortunately, preview seems to add these bookmarks directly into the PDF rather than in some config file, making it difficult to manually alter the contents.

Comment: As of 2023, the issue is still unresolved. @sayzlim's workaround becomes ineffective if other annotations are applied to the document, such as underlines, highlights, text boxes, etc, as ALL annotations are shown in the sidebar, which quickly becomes messy

Answer (score 22):

Instead of using **Bookmarks**, you can use **Notes** as the replacement to use custom title for bookmarked pages. They serve the same function, with **Notes** having more versatile usage.

1. Show the **Highlights & Notes** in sidebar by pressing `Command+Option+4`.
2. To create a note, you can choose `Tools > Annotate > Notes` or by pressing `Command+Control+N`.
3. Select everywhere on the screen and write down the title for your bookmarks (You can also pick the notes background color).

Here’s the screenshot how it looks like:

[image: Bookmarks with custom title in Preview]

I’m not sure which Preview version support this,but it should be available after OS X Lion 10.7.

Comment: Pretty nifty workaround, hadn't thought about that. I guess only Apple can fix the real issue, and I probably should get myself together and file a bug report. Meanwhile, this will be my solution!